# xpath get top most parent for a matched node or its child node

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have xml node like this directly under root,

```
<online.png>
 <createdBy>admin</createdBy>
 <mimeType>image/png</mimeType> // may be here in node itself
 <primaryType>nt:file</primaryType>
 <content>
    <firstName>Vendor</firstName>
    <mimeType>image/png</mimeType>  // may be here in child 
    <city>Hyderabad</city>
 </content>
</online.png>
```

From this node, how to get the top-parent(here gif image node) irrespective of mimetype position using xpath, and also I want to first get the node name based on its value like search. ie,

```
stirng xpath = select top-paren where element name has value ('image/')
           / --    "//*[contains(text(),'image/')] select top parent"
```

any suggestion is appreciated.

```
XmlNodeList nodeImages = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//*[contains(text(),'image/')]");
```

returns both content node and gif node. I want only gif node

Comment: I searched your xml for `gif` and didn't find anything

Comment: sorry, it's png not gif

Comment: You want to select `<online.png>` element?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "*top-parent*" you mean `<online.png>` in your example, the answer is pretty simple: `/*[//*[contains(text(), 'image')]]` - in other words, "*any element contained directly by the root element, which contains at any depth an element that contains the text 'image'*".

Comment: thank you, for your answer, but the result I get when I run this query is 'root' node, instead of online.png node.

Comment: Perhaps you should give us the XML **containing** the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get element on second level (i.e. which is placed directly under root) with any of it's children elements contains text `image/` then use xpath:

```
"/*/*[//*[contains(text(), 'image/')]]"
```